# Can an element in a ring with unity be both a unit and zero-divisor?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know this cannot be true for $\Bbb Z_n$, but is this also true in general rings? If so, how can you prove this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While for a field there is a condition specifying that $1\neq 0$, there's no such requirement for general rings. This is the only time a unit can be a zero divisor: in the ring with one element, $0$ is both a unit and a zero divisor. As the other answers show, as soon as $1\neq 0$ this is not possible.

Comment: but the usual definition of a zero divisor is an element $a$ such that $ax=0$ for non-zero $x$

Comment: @Jorge True, but I think it's fair to include an exception that $0$ is always a zero divisor.

Comment: What? So in a field, it's possible for 1 = 0? That is hard to conceive. Isn't that statement a contradiction that can't be made? What would be the inverse of 0 be?

Comment: @user No, it's explicitly prohibited in a field. But in a ring you can have $1=0$. In that case the ring must have exactly one element, that is, $0$, and it is a multiplicative identity and its own inverse.

Comment: @MattSamuel Is that the only ring that 1 = 0?

Comment: @user Yes. Otherwise $0x=0\neq x$ for all $x\neq 0$.

Answer (score 9):

Suppose $a$ is an invertible zero-divisor.Then there is a nonzero $x$ so that $ax=0$.

It follows that $x=1x=(a^{-1}a)x=a^{-1}(ax)=a^{-1}0=0$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 5):

No, it can not. Let $R$ be a ring and let $u\in R$. Assume that $u$ is a unit of $R$ and let $x\in R$ such that $ux=0$. Left-multiplying this equality by the inverse of $u$ leads to $x=0$. Therefore, $u$ is not a zero-divisor of $R$.